# Group coordinates by proximity to each other

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, coordinates

I'm building a REST API so the answer can't include google maps or javascript stuff.
In our app, we have a table containing posts that looks like that :

```
  ID |   latitude   | longitude   | other_sutff
   1 | 50.4371243   |  5.9681102  |    ...
   2 | 50.3305477   |  6.9420498  |    ...
   3 | -33.4510148  | 149.5519662 |    ...
```

We have a view with a map that shows all the posts around the world.
Hopefully, we will have a lot of posts and it will be ridiculous to show thousands and thousands of markers in the map. So we want to group them by proximity so we can have something like 2-3 markers by continent.

To be clear, we need this :
[image]
*Image from https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer*

I've done some research and found that k-means seems to be part of the solution.
As I am really really bad at Math, I tried a couple of php libraries like this one : https://github.com/bdelespierre/php-kmeans that seems to do a decent job.
However, there is a drawback : I have to parse all the table each time the map is loaded. Performance-wise, it's awful.

So I would like to know if someone already got through this problematic or if there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you cache the result of your clustering to increase performance? In the database or some other sort of caching layer (APC if you are using an older version of PHP) for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure, the app works in a way that there will be a continuous creation/destruction of data.

Comment: Okay, this is interesting. I think this is a good example where caching is sometimes a trade-off, where you need to decide between real-time information and performance. Which means it's a huge grey area... But some questions you could ask yourself are: how many times in a given time (say a minute) do I need to serve this data? How long does it take to process the SQL request - seconds or minutes? Does it matter if the data shown is not exactly real-time, say 30 seconds, 1 minute, 2 minutes old? The goal is to decide what your users will find acceptable. Often performance > freshness.

Comment: In addition to this, focus on your data. Are there ways to speed up the queries, either by looking at indexing (where appropriate) or profiling the efficiency of my queries? Are there ways to continuously, or periodically, pre-calculate the result set?

Comment: Actually, i'm not worried about my SQL query which is a simple select-from-where even if of course, some table optimization is required. I think the slowest part is on the PHP side looping on my query results and building the groups. But yes you are right in my opinion, the data could be 5mins old but my client wants real real-time. I'll take a look at what I can do with OPcache. Thanks for your suggestions @Darragh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I kept searching and I've found an alternative to KMeans : **GEOHASH**

Wikipedia will explain better than me what it is : [Wiki geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)

But to summarize, The world map is divided in a grid of 32 cells and to each one is given an alpha-numeric character.
Each cell is also divided into 32 cells and so on for 12 levels.
So if I do a `GROUP BY` on the first letter of hash I will get my clusters for the lowest zoom level, if I want more precision, I just need to group by the first N letters of my hash.

So, what I've done is only added one field to my table and generate the hash corresponding to my coordinates:

```
ID |   latitude   | longitude   | geohash      | other_sutff
 1 | 50.4371243   |  5.9681102  | csyqm73ymkh2 |     ...
 2 | 50.3305477   |  6.9420498  | p24k1mmh98eu |     ...
 3 | -33.4510148  | 149.5519662 | 8x2s9674nd57 |     ...
```

Now, if I want to get my clusters, I just have to do a simple query :

```
SELECT count(*) as nb_markers FROM mtable GROUP BY SUBSTRING(geohash,1,2);
```

*In the substring, 2 is level of precision and must be between 1 and 12*

PS : [Lib I used to generate my hash](https://github.com/nowelium/geohash-mysql-func)